# mysql executeBatch() error..?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

In the MySQL environment, I use jdbc `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()`
When you run a batch update, the entire query does not run,
Only the last query will run normally.

I do not know what to check.

My source code

```
ps = conn.prepareStatement ("update TEMP set LAST_UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE () where id = '1001'");
ps.addBatch ();

ps = conn.prepareStatement ("update TEMP set LAST_UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE () where id = '1002'");
ps.addBatch ();

ps = conn.prepareStatement ("update TEMP set LAST_UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE () where id = '1003'");
ps.addBatch ();

Int result [] = ps.executeBatch ();
```

Comment: I'm unclear how you'd ever get the idea that this would even work: you are creating multiple prepared statements, call `addBatch` on them and then only call `executeBatch` on the last one. Of course it is only going to execute that last one, because that is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly incorrect use of prepared statements. You probably had simple statements in mind when you wrote this. For prepared statement batch, the approach is slightly different

```
// first create the prepared statement
ps = conn.prepareStatement ("update TEMP set LAST_UPDATE_DT = SYSDATE () where id = ?");
// then bind to it.
ps.setInt(1,1001);
ps.addBatch();

// then bind again
ps.setInt(1,1002);
ps.addBatch();

// and again
ps.setInt(1,1003);
ps.addBatch();

int result [] = ps.executeBatch ();
```